# Adding two numbers using linked lists

Tags: c++

I am trying to add two numbers that are represented by linked lists. So I have inserted the numbers 3->2->8 and 6->5->4. I have tried to get the numbers 328 and 654 and then added the two and insert them in a third list. I am facing some problems while calculating the number. Here is the code.

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


struct Node{
int data;
struct Node *next;
};
int flag=1;
void input(Node **head,int num)
{
    Node *temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data=num;
    if(!flag)temp->next=*head;
    if(flag){temp->next=NULL;flag=0;}
    *head=temp;
}

void add(Node *l1,Node *l2,Node *l3)
{
    Node *cur1=l1;
    Node *cur2=l2;
    int size1=0,size2=0;

    while(cur1!=NULL)
    {
       size1++;

        cur1=cur1->next;
    }
    while(cur2!=NULL)
    {
        size2++;
        cur2=cur2->next;
    }
    int i=size1-1,j=size2-1,sum1=0,sum2=0;
    cur1=l1;cur2=l2;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    while(cur1!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<cur1->data<<"\t";
        cout<<cur1->data*pow(10,i)<<"\t";

        sum1=sum1+cur1->data*pow(10,i);
        cout<<sum1<<endl;
        i--;
        cur1=cur1->next;
    }
    cout<<sum1<<endl;
    while(cur2!=NULL)
    {    cout<<cur2->data<<"\t";
        cout<<cur2->data*pow(10,j)<<"\t";
        sum2=sum2+cur2->data*pow(10,j);
        cout<<sum2<<endl;
        j--;
        cur2=cur2->next;
    }
    cout<<sum2<<endl;
    sum1+=sum2;
    while(sum1!=0)
    {
        int r=sum1%10;
        input(&l3,r);
        sum1/=10;
    }
    cur1=l3;
    while(cur1!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<cur1->data;
        cur1=cur1->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Node *l1=NULL;
    Node *l2=NULL;
    Node *l3=NULL;
    input(&l1,8);
    input(&l1,2);
    input(&l1,3);
    flag=1;
    input(&l2,4);
    input(&l2,5);
    input(&l2,6);
    add(l1,l2,l3);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the output

```
2 //value of i
3       300     299 //cur1->data*pow(10,i) is initially 300 then becomes 299
2       20      319
8       8       327
327 //total sum which should be 328
6       600     599 //Same problem 
5       50      649
4       4       653
653 //total sum which should be 654
980 //sum of 327 and 653
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? Looks like C++ - if so, please edit your tags accordingly.

Comment: In this example, you know that the two numbers have the same number of digits, but in general, you probably wouldn't.  Also, in this example, the result has the same number of digits as the inputs, but the output could have one more digit than the input (consider adding 499 and 501, for example).  You have to be able to backtrack to deal with carries (in the case of 499 + 501, you'd have to backtrack twice, and add a new element at the start of the result; with 328 + 654, you only have to backtrack once.  I'm probably not telling you anything you weren't aware of, but just in case.

Comment: To tonysdg : Sorry I was using structures and thought of C. And to Jonathan  : No I do not know how many digits each linked list has. This is why I have the variable size1 and size2 which calculates their sizes respectively. And yes, I checked it out. It works for different sized lists too.

Comment: No worries - just wanted to make sure you had the proper support! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be due to truncation. The `pow` function returns floating point. Then you convert it to integer which causes a truncation.

Example:

```
299.99999999 as float will become 299 as int
```

Try to add 0.5 first to get rounding instead.

Like:

```
sum1=sum1+(cur1->data*pow(10,i) + 0.5);
```

As commented by @viraptor it is even better to avoid float (i.e. pow). Try something like:

```
sum1 = 0;
while(cur1 != NULL)
{
    sum1 = 10 * sum1;
    sum1 = sum1 + cur1->data;
    cur1=cur1->next;
}
```

then all calculations are done on integers and you will not get problems due to conversion between float and int.

Comment: Or even better - get rid of floating point completely. `sum1*=10; sum1+=cur1;` No `pow`, no rounding, no need to count `i`.

Comment: @viraptor - I agree. I just tried to explain what was going on. But yes - floating point should be avoided when possible - and it is possible here.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with 0.5. And yes I'll keep in mind to avoid them. Learnt a new thing today :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit difficult to follow. You could simply sum the (simply) linked lists instead of extracting the values of each list, add them, and then store the result.

Below a simple example. Note that `carry` must be passed as reference, so the caller has access to the modified value when unwinding the stack. Also, this example assumes both lists have the same number of nodes. If not, you could add `0`'s to the shortest list.

```
// basic node structure
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data = 0;
    Node<T>* next = nullptr;
};

// function to sum 2 simply linked lists
Node<int>* sumLists(Node<int>* l1, Node<int>* l2, int& carry, int k = -1)
{
    if (!l1 && !l2)
    {
        // we reached the end of both lists
        return nullptr;
    }

    ++k; // index of the largest list

    // iterate to the end of both lists, head is the head of the result list
    auto head = sumLists(l1 ? l1->next : l1, l2 ? l2->next : l2, carry, k);

    // compute the value and carry
    int value = carry;
    if (l1) value += l1->data;
    if (l2) value += l2->data;
    carry = value / 10;

    // insert the value into the result list
    Node<int>* node = new Node<int>();
    node->data = value % 10;
    if (!head)
    {
        head = node;
    }
    else
    {
        node->next =head;
        head = node;
    }

    // add carry for the last iteration
    if ((k == 0) && (carry != 0))
    {
        Node<int>* node = new Node<int>();
        node->data = carry;
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
    }

    return head;
}
```